# ADL using `std::size_t`

Tags: c++, std, argument-dependent-lookup

Why is it that `std::size_t` does not seem to trigger ADL within the std namespace?

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/x13wVE):

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

std::size_t i{1}; //doesn't seem to trigger ADL
//std::vector i{1}; //triggers ADL
auto k = make_tuple(i);
```

Comment: TL;DR: `std::size_t` is a type alias for one of the fundamental types (which do not come from `namespace std` originally).